# Elegant way to log actions?

Tags: java, swing, logging, action

Say you have an application with a series of actions. How would you write it such that actions are logged when they are triggered?

1. Use a Template pattern.
2. Use AOP.
3. Use a Listener and Events.
4. Use a combination of the above.
5. Something else (explain).

Comment: why not log4j entries when methods called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd vote for AOP for the sake of eliminating redundancy, but only if there's room for AOP in your project.
You can have custom logging using a logging library from your methods elsewhere in your project, but in a particular component where you hold many similar classes and want to log similar things for all of them, it can be painful to copy/paste and make sure everyone knows how to log.

EDIT: regarding the other enumerated approaches, I think the advantage of AOP would be that it doesn't require you to design your code (template methods or events) specifically for this topic. You usually don't lose any of the code flexibility when spotting cross-cutting concerns and treating them as such, as opposed to redesigning a whole class hierarchy just to make use of consistent logging.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer is using log4j (or sli4j, if that's the latest) inside an aspect.

Logging is the "hello world" of AOP.  If you aren't using AOP, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It really would depend on your specific context. Specifically on what was being tracked and how the application currently worked.  If the actions are classes that all have a common base class and all you care about is the name of the action, then a simple addition to log in this class would be a great choice.  If you have actions spread across several layers of code, then an AOP or Listener/Event type solution might work better.   If that application was a web app vs desktop or if you ultimately need the logs feed to a database, webservice, or just want text files all make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

if you simply want to log particular actions it's probably simplest to use a [logging api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/index.html) such as [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) or [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) etc add a log statement in the code you wish to track.